# Renaming gulp task

Tags: gulp

I'm inheriting a plugin that has a complex build which is invoked by gulp build. I managed to extend the processing by appending some of my stuff but I'm unable to keep the original task name.

```
gulp.task('customBuild', function(cb) {
  runSequence(
      'build',   ///<-- inherited stuff
      'build:svg:delete',
      'build:svg',
      'build:war',
      cb
  );
});
```

What I want to achieve is that the sequence will be triggered by

```
gulp build
```

Is it possible to rename gulp task and how to do it without the modification of the 3th party plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp tasks are just functions that have been registered under a certain name and with certain dependencies. "Renaming" a task is just the act of registering the function and dependencies under a new name.

The following reregisters the third party `build` task under the new `originalBuild` name and then overwrites the `build` task with your own.

```
gulp.task('originalBuild', gulp.tasks['build'].dep, gulp.tasks['build'].fn);

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  runSequence(
      'originalBuild',   ///<-- inherited stuff
      'build:svg:delete',
      'build:svg',
      'build:war',
      cb
  );
});
```